# how to use Array with if else statements?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have this code:

```
 String[] sweetFlevors = { "Caramel", "Cinnamon", "Wetermelon", "Backed Beans" };

 String[] savoryFlavors = { "Sea Salt", "Potato Chip", "Carrot", "Barbque" };

 int[] numberRows = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 int[] numberCol = { 1, 2 };

 for (int col = 0; col < numberCol.length; col++) {
     System.out.println("       " + numberCol[0] + "         " + numberCol[1]);

     for (String sweet: sweetFlevors) {
         for (String savory: savoryFlavors) {

             for (int row = 0; row < numberRows.length; row++) {
                 System.out.print(numberRows[row] + ". ");

                 System.out.println(sweet + " and " + savory);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

and my Output is something like this:

```
    1         2
1. Caramel and Sea Salt
2. Caramel and Sea Salt
3. Caramel and Sea Salt
2. Wetermelon and Carrot
3. Backed Beans and Barbque
4. Backed Beans and Barbque
       1         2     //  How to delete this line?
1. Caramel and Sea Salt
2. Caramel and Sea Salt
```

I dont know how I can delete the second line column? and why I get it?

thanks you for help me :)

Comment: What you ask is really not clear. You should explain what you want to do, what you get and please format your code in a readable way.

Comment: I have to practice ARRAY and therefore I do all sorts of code exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the column header twice because you have put it inside the `for` loop `for (int col = 0; col < numberCol.length; col++)`. You have to do it like this:

```
String[] sweetFlevors = { "Caramel", "Cinnamon", "Wetermelon", "Backed Beans" };

String[] savoryFlavors = { "Sea Salt", "Potato Chip", "Carrot", "Barbque" };

int[] numberRows = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] numberCol = { 1, 2 };

System.out.println("       " + numberCol[0] + "         " + numberCol[1]);
for (int col = 0; col < numberCol.length; col++) {
    for (String sweet: sweetFlevors) {
        for (String savory: savoryFlavors) {
            for (int row = 0; row < numberRows.length; row++) {
                System.out.print(numberRows[row] + ". ");

                System.out.println(sweet + " and " + savory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```